# Allow streaming data in VBA UserForm

Tags: excel, userform, bloomberg, vba

I have built a UserForm that I would like to stream some market data I'm pulling from Bloomberg into an Excel sheet. I launch the UserForm, and it displays the correct initial data, but when the data updates in the spreadsheet, it does not update in the UserForm TextBox. This makes sense, but I'm looking for a workaround. Is there some way to allow it to stream this data and update in real time? Or should I be using something other than a TextBox?

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using to paint the initial values:

```
Private Sub MonitorOnly_Click()

Sheets("Log").Activate

OTCBid.Text = Range("C3")
OTCAsk.Text = Range("D3")
OTCBidSize.Text = Range("E3")
OTCAskSize.Text = Range("F3")

ICEBid.Text = Range("C5")
ICEAsk.Text = Range("D5")
ICEBidSize.Text = Range("E5")
ICEAskSize.Text = Range("F5")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. I can use the .ControlSource property of the TextBox to link the TextBox to the streaming data. Here is what the working code looks like:

```
Private Sub MonitorOnly_Click()

Sheets("Log").Activate

OTCBid.ControlSource = "=C3"
OTCAsk.ControlSource = "=D3"
OTCBidSize.ControlSource = "=F3"
OTCAskSize.ControlSource = "=E3"

ICEBid.ControlSource = "=C4"
ICEAsk.ControlSource = "=D4"
ICEBidSize.ControlSource = "=F4"
ICEAskSize.ControlSource = "=E4"

End Sub
```